# How to get the first 3 digits from a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

So I have got a column and i want to get the first 3 digits only from it and store them in a function called wnS using the split function or any other method that would work. I want to get the first three digits before "_"

I tried doing this but it didn't work, and I also kept getting "TypeError: wnC.split is not a function"

```
    var ssh = ssPO.getSheetByName("PO for OR (East).csv")
    wnC = ssh.getRange("N2:N");
    var wnS = wnC.split("_");
```

[image]

I would really appreciate an answer

If you need more info please let me know

Thank you.

Comment: First of all wnC is a range not a string.  Did you want to use getValues()?  And if you do it would be a 2 dimensional array so you would need to index it wnC[i][0].

Comment: Yeah but I thought that i need to get the range of column N and then use wnS to go over it and split the data and save them in wnS. Isnt that how it work?   I honestly dont know but if it works then sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you define range, you have to get the values.

```
function first_3_digs (){
    
        var ssh = ssPO.getSheetByName("PO for OR (East).csv")
        var wnC = ssh.getRange("N2:N");
        var values = wnC.getValues();
        const first_3_digs = values.filter(r => {
            if(r.toString().includes('_')){return r;}
        }).map(r=> r.toString().split('_')[0]);
        console.log(first_3_digs)
    }
```

Comment: It worked    thank you so much.  <3

Answer (score 1):

```
const cell = "(303) 987-4567";
const first3 = cell.match(/\d{3}/)[0];
//result:303
```

[String method match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

[regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt)

BTW: you can test methods like this very easily in the console.log in the browsers developer tools.

Comment: I'm Sorry. I'm a beginner with js. Can you explain to me what is that please?

Comment: It's a method of Javascript String objects which uses regular expressions to find matches.  Look in any javascript reference and they will have a lot written about it.

Comment: Im getting an error saying cell is not defirned

Comment: I tried adding wnc. before it and i got Cannot read property 'match' of undefined. Do you know how to fix that?